# Asynchronous Function Halting Synchronous Function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, discord.js

So I have a synchronous function (`client.functionOne`) that is creating a Discord.js message collector, which deletes messages sent to a channel. This function also calls an asynchronous function which creates a `setTimeout` loop.

The issue is, for some reason, the "collect" function gets held up whenever the code in `client.functionTwo` is run and it does not run as fast as it would if it wasn't running.

I am unsure why it is doing this. Could someone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
client.functionTwo = async (channel) => {
    let timeout;

    const interval = async () => {
        // Logic here with several awaits

        // Schedule a new timeout
        timeout = setTimeout(interval, 2000);
    }

    interval();
}

client.functionOne = (channel) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(() => true, { time: 150000 });

        client.functionTwo(channel);        

        collector.on("collect", (message) => {
            if (message.author.bot) return;

            message.delete();
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call any function that creates a  `setTimeout` or calls `functionTwo` "synchronous".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive testing I was able to determine that my issue was caused by rate limiting with Discord and the JavaScript library I am using.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //  client.functionTwo = async (channel) => {
   // let timeout = await setTimeout(interval, 2000);
   // }

client.functionOne = async (channel) => {
    const collector = await channel.createMessageCollector(() => => true, 
    { time: 150000 });
  //   await client.functionOne(channel);        
collector.on("collect", async (message) => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
await message.delete();
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. After extensive testing I was able to determine that my issue was caused by rate limiting with Discord and the JavaScript library I am using.